# Removing URL strings from a .csv that contain specific substrings

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have written the below code, which is definitely removing some URLs from the list but I see many still containing the parameters I'm looking for.

I added the

```
row[0].lower()
```

to try remedy this but it still doesn't work.

The URLs with parameters look like this:

?currentPage=2&Nrpp=24&No=24
?pagination=1&currentPage=2

Does it have something to do with the "?"?

```
import csv

values =  [
   "/blog",
   "nrpp",
   "pagination"
]  

added_vals = []

with open("internal_all_dup_facets.csv", "rt", encoding="utf-8") as inp, open("dupfacets.csv", "w", newline='') as out:
  writer = csv.writer(out)
  for row in csv.reader(inp):
     for value in values:
         if value not in row[0].lower() and row[0] not in added_vals:
            writer.writerow(row)
         added_vals.append(row[0])
```

The file should return the same file basically but with significantly less rows. Some example URLs can be found below:

> /category/dresses-5699972/juna-rose/N-ihuZ20cbZc1y?currentPage=29&Nrpp=24&No=672
>   /category/dresses-5699972/tall-dresses-204374/purple/N-ij9ZbyvZc1y
>   /category/dresses-5699972/pencil-dresses-204531/short-sleeve/N-iisZ21b9Zc1y?pagination=1&currentPage=2
>   /category/dresses-5699972/tan/N-ihuZbyyZc1y?currentPage=10&Nrpp=24&No=216

Comment: What's the purpose of `added_vals`?  Do you only want to remove the first occurrence of a row?

Comment: So i have a for within a for, which at the moment results in 3 instances of every URL (because I have 3 values).  So added_vals adds things to a list once, instead of the 3 times.

It's not pretty but it works.  Only been coding for a few months.

Comment: that might be the problem. Your `added_vals` is, first of all, super slow, and second, it prevents duplicates from happening. Let me propose an answer for you. If it doesn't fix it, we need an example csv, otherwise we cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: You provided some url, could you also show how the output should be like? Something like 'input' > 'expected result'?

Comment: Sure thing.  If I've correctly understood what you want me to show it's the following:
Input Column A in the CSV:
/category/dresses-5699972/juna-rose/N-ihuZ20cbZc1y?currentPage=29&Nrpp=24&No=672 /category/dresses-5699972/tall-dresses-204374/purple/N-ij9ZbyvZc1y 
/category/dresses-5699972/pencil-dresses-204531/short-sleeve/N-iisZ21b9Zc1y?pagination=1&currentPage=2 


Output Column A in the CSV:
/category/dresses-5699972/tall-dresses-204374/purple/N-ij9ZbyvZc1y

Comment: If you ask a question like this, you should specify what the wanted behaviour is. We cannot guess what you are trying to do. Now that you provided a CSV example, let me try to formulate one: `"I have a number of URLs in a CSV file with a single column, and a list of search strings. I want to copy all URLs to a new CSV file, excluding all URLs that contain at least one of the search strings."`. Is this correct? If yes, I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: In my humble, amateur opinion my title explains exactly what I'm trying to do: remove certain urls based on what is inside them. The way you have described it also works, so to conclude yes I'm trying to copy over URLs and all the horizontal columns that  are also in the sheet - basically I don't just want one column with clean URLs.  The .csv is a Screaming Frog crawl if that is familiar.

Comment: 1. you don't *remove* certain urls. That would mean deleting them from the original csv. 2. you do not specify what the data format inside the input and output csv is. 3. you do not specify with which criterium you want to filter the urls. All three are important informations without which the implementation is not possible. Further, that information should be in your description instead of your title. But as you don't explicitely specify, we have to guess those 3 parameters, and from your code it wasn't clear. It became clearer with the data, but explicitly specifying it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your `added_vals` variable does, but I think you are overcomplicating things.

It should be fixable pretty easily:

```
import csv

values =  [
   "/blog",
   "nrpp",
   "pagination"
]

# Open input and output files
with open("internal_all_dup_facets.csv", "rt", encoding="utf-8") as inp, open("dupfacets.csv", "w", newline='') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)

    # Iterate through the rows in the file
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        url = row[0].lower()

        # Iterate through the values, and see if one matches
        for value in values:
            # If we find a match, cancel the current `for` loop
            if value in url:
                break
        else:
            # This will only run if we finished the `for` loop without a `break`.
            # So, if we reached this code, no match was found
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The code would get even more compact if you used regular expressions:

```
import csv
import re

rx = re.compile(r"^[^?]*/blog|[?&](currentPage|nrpp)=", re.IGNORECASE)

with open("internal_all_dup_facets.csv", "rt", encoding="utf-8") as inp, open("dupfacets.csv", "w", newline='') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)

    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if not rx.search(row[0]):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Alternative version, closer to your original code:

```
import csv

values =  [
   "/blog",
   "nrpp",
   "pagination"
]

# Open input and output files
with open("internal_all_dup_facets.csv", "rt", encoding="utf-8") as inp, open("dupfacets.csv", "w", newline='') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)

    # Iterate through the rows in the file
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        url = row[0].lower()

        # Iterate through the values, and see if one matches
        matches = False
        for value in values:
            if value in url:
                matches = True
                break

        # If none match, write to output csv
        if not matches:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I like this solution, I'll give it a try

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't work.  It returns something really messed up.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Just like that? No explanation what so ever? At least provide a csv example, so I can test the code ...

Comment: Sorry about that.  I added a few relative URLs in the post above.  I have no idea how to add a .csv

Comment: Understood what you are trying to do (next time please specify), should now work. Produces your example result on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem: you iterate over your three values. So you test if the first value is in `row[0]`. If it's not, you still add the row[0] to your `added_vals`, so this row won't be tested anymore and won't be able to be written.

What you should do is something like:

```
for row in csv.reader(inp):
     if not any(v.lower() in row.lower() for v in values):
         writer.writerow(row)
```

Also, you could have a lot of false-negatives with the use of `in`, so this would be even better:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r".*\?currentPage=\d+&Nrpp=\d+&No=\d+\?pagination=\d+&currentPage=\d+.*", re.IGNORECASE)

for row in csv.reader(inp):
     if not rx.match(row):
         writer.writerow(row)
```

> More about regex: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll get to reading the Regex documentation so I can figure out what's going on here.

Comment: unfortunately your code doesn't work, error stated:
  File "CVS_retrieval.py", line 28
    if not rx.match(row[0])
                          ^

Comment: Could you post more of this error? What is the exception and the message with it?

Comment: There is no error, but the output is wrong in the dupfacets.csv.  It still contains things that should have been excluded.  I have added some example URL subdirectories in the original question post.  Apologies for not being clear and slow responses - this is a side project at work, you see.